# Allow GKE to access the DB inside the VM GCP Compute engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-kubernetes-engine, google-compute-engine, windows-firewall

I have a GKE Cluster and a Compute engine(windows). Compute engine has DB in it.
Both GKE and compute engine are in same region, VPC network, subnet.
DB, VM firewall has the allowed IP address for GKE pods IP range, Cluster IP(internal and external)

How can GKE access the DB? Do I need anything else configured?

**EDIT**

If I try to connect same DB from Another VM in same VPC it works with the below connection string but fails with GKE.

Error I face while connection -

**Connection string**

```
Server=Name;Database=ABC;User Id=sqlserver;password=123;Integrated Security=True;
```

**Error**

```
Connection id "0HMTRR0OO74L6", Request id "0HMTRR0OO74L6:00000003": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot authenticate using Kerberos. Ensure Kerberos has been initialized on the client with 'kinit' and a Service Principal Name has been registered for the SQL Server to allow Kerberos authentication.
      ErrorCode=InternalError, Exception=Interop+NetSecurityNative+GssApiException: GSSAPI operation failed with error - Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (SPNEGO cannot find mechanisms to negotiate).
```

Comment: just the IP if all the other things are green!

Comment: IP of what resource?

Comment: The IP of your compute engine hosting the database.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail, where should I add the ip of vm ?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. From your GKE pods use the database IP address (the private IP of the VM hosting the VM). If you really put all in the same VPC with the correct firewall rule, it will work immediately. I don't know what you tried and where you are stuck, but this kind of connectivity is a no brainer.

Comment: Are you able to ping from your pod to the GCE db instance? (hopefully, you are, otherwise you might see a timeout error, please verify) And are you able to establish a db connection from your code on your local machine before deploying it to a GKE? What language/API/library are you using? What is the base image for your container?

Comment: as @Venkat suggested, checking if pod can access to db ip or will give idea on network issue, you can use any command like `ping`, `telnet`, `ssh`(not windows) from pod to db.